# Tkinter Button class creation

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, inheritance

I am trying to create a class, which will help me to optimize/organize creation of another Tkinter buttons. I am aware that an inheritance should have been used. I've been trying to do something like this:

```
from tkinter import *    

window = Tk()
window.title("Button class app")

upper_frame = Frame(window)
upper_frame.pack(fill="both", side=TOP, expand=1)

lower_frame = Frame(window)
lower_frame.pack(fill="both", side=BOTTOM, expand=1)

function1 = None
function2 = None

class Buttons(Button):
    def __init__(self, master, text, command):
        Button().__init__(self)  # or super(). method 
        self.master=master
        self.text=text
        self.command=command
        self.font=("Comic Sans", 30)
        self.fg="#7df9ff",
        self.bg="#FFFF00",
        self.activeforeground="#7df9ff",
        self.activebackground="#FFFF00",
        self.state=ACTIVE,
        self.compound='bottom',
button1 = Buttons(upper_frame, "Some text 1", function1)     
button1.pack(fill="x")

button2 = Buttons(lower_frame, "Some text 2", function2)     
button2.pack(fill="x")
```

I've been trying to use `super()` method instead of `Button().__ init __()`, but I am not sure what arguments should I pass on to/what should I really inherit. Using `super()`.

> method gives me error: 'Buttons' object has no attribute 'tk'.

Somehow, also with `Button(). __ init __` I could also get access to i.e.: `self["text"]=text,` but not with `self.text=text` as usual (why?)

I've been also trying to make a class for main Tkinter window, and then for frames - to make inheritance for a Tkinter Button Class object - but I think this is not the way it should work - I think I should make an inheritance from predefined Tkinter Button/tk.Button class.

I will be very grateful for any help or explanations.

Comment: `Button().__init__(self)` is incorrect.  Either use `Button.__init__(self, master)` or `super().__init__(master)` instead.  Also `self.text = text` will not change the text of the button.  Use either `self['text'] = text` or `self.config(text=text)` instead.

Comment: maybe in other GUIs you could use `self.text` but `tkinter` doesn't use `self.text` but `self['text']`. You would have to create `def text(self)` with `@property` to use `self.text = ...`

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Answer (score 1):

In other GUIs you could use `self.text` but `tkinter` uses

```
self['text'] = text
```

```
self.config(text=text)
```

And the same with other values (maybe except `master`)

It allow also

```
self.config(text=text, command=command)
```

```
self.config({"text":text, "command":command})
```

```
setting = {'text': 'other', 'bg': 'red'}
self.config(setting)
```

```
setting = {'text': 'other', 'bg': 'red'}
self.config(**setting)  # with `**` to unpack dictionary
```

---

Full working code.

`import *` is not preferred - using `import tkinter as tk` I can create class with name `Button` (without `s`) and use three different classes at the same time: `tk.Button`, `ttk.Button` and my `Button`.

In `__init__` I use `**kwargs` so I can send other parameters to class.

```
import tkinter as tk   # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- classes ---  # PEP8: all classes after imports

class Button(tk.Button):
    
    def __init__(self, master, text, command, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, text=text, command=command)
        
        #self.master = master
        
        #self['text'] = text         # PEP8: spaces around `=`
        #self['command'] = command
        
        self['font'] = ("Comic Sans", 30)
        self['fg'] = "#7df9ff"
        self['bg'] = "#FFFF00"
        self['activeforeground'] = "#7df9ff"
        self['activebackground'] = "#FFFF00"
        self['state'] = 'active'
        self['compound'] = 'bottom'
        
        self.config(**kwargs)

# --- functions ---   # PEP8: all functions after classes (before main code)

def function1():
    print('function1')
    
def function2():
    print('function2')

# --- main ---

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Button class app")

upper_frame = tk.Frame(window)
upper_frame.pack(fill="both", side=TOP, expand=1)

lower_frame = tk.Frame(window)
lower_frame.pack(fill="both", side=BOTTOM, expand=1)


button1 = Button(upper_frame, "Some text 1", function1, bg='red', activebackground='blue')     
button1.pack(fill="x")

button2 = Button(lower_frame, "Some text 2", function2, bg='green', activebackground='blue')     
button2.pack(fill="x")

window.mainloop()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)